# Integrating video lib without node.js or npm

Tags: plyr, video.js

I have an absolute beginner question: I am a hobby coder and coming from the time, when integrating a library in my own project was downloading xx.js and xx.css on GitHub, puting them in the header and everything worked fine.

Today I tried to integrate the libraries Plyr.js and Video.js to my project, but without a CDN. So I downloaded them on GitHub, but they don't contain compiled css.

How can I integrate them on a shared Webhosting without any Node.js, NPM etc.?

(Sorry for that maybe stupid question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dist versions of complex projects aren't typically checked into version control. You can use Video.js's CDN hosted dist versions as mentioned [here](https://videojs.com/getting-started/#videojs-cdn).

```
<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.18.1/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.18.1/video.min.js"></script>
```

For NPM packages generally, you can use a service like [unpkg](https://unpkg.com/) or [jsdelivr](https://www.jsdelivr.com/) to get CDN hosted versions of dist files, e.g.

```
https://unpkg.com/browse/video.js@7.18.1/dist/video.min.js
https://unpkg.com/browse/video.js@7.18.1/dist/video-js.css
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/video.js@7.18.1/dist/video.min.js
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/video.js@7.18.1/dist/video-js.css
```

If you don't want to directly use the URLs, you can download the dist files from there.

Alternatively you can look at the releases page on GitHub, where you'll find a zip archive of files, e.g. https://github.com/videojs/video.js/releases

Comment: Thank you, but I want to do it without CDN as mentioned in my question (due to data protection requirements in the European Union). How can I get the compiled files? Is there any official source for plyr.js and video.js?

Comment: You can download it from those locations.